# How to set LXPanel opacity?

Tags: lubuntu, appearance, lxpanel

In appearance settings there is "Solid Background" option checked with 0 opacity, but LXPanel background is same as wallpaper, not the window it covers. How to make it right?
Here are two screenshots:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, 0 is fully transparent. 255 would be fully opaque.

Comment: On 0 it's must not have any background. Instead, as you can see on screenshots, it's just using wallpaper as background. I still cant see anything thru it.

Comment: it could be fake transparency, it works without a compositor